# Configure Code collaborator to assign reviewers as per ownership

Tags: code-collaborator

In our team it has been proposed to mandate the checkins to be reviewed by respective feature/class owners(Assuming the owners are the ones who checked in the file first)
Can Code collaborator be configured such that on raising code review request respective class owners are added as reviewers by default

Answer (score 2):

Code Collaborator implements "File ownership" using a feature called "Subscriptions".  See here in Code Collaborator's manual: http://smartbear.com/docs/manual/5.0/index.html?ws_user_prefs.html#file-subscriptions

Comment: It allows to configure for particular file.That is we have to manually subscribe for each file or file pattern.
I am looking for some configuration where in file creator will be default reviewer

Comment: It's more work, but you could do this using a Code Collaborator trigger and command-line scripting.

1) Configure the Code Collaborator "Added Files" trigger to call your script (http://tinyurl.com/2cth4xo), passing the review id and paths of the files using the ${review.id} and ${files.paths} substitution variables.

2) In your script, look up who the authors of those files in your version control system, then add those users as reviewers to the review using the "ccollab admin review participant assign" command.  (http://tinyurl.com/2whwjxz)

Contact support@smartbear.com if you need help!